# How to disable autofill Magento login in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

When I enter to my login page the login form is filled automatically without even typing anything, this is pseudo-code

```
<li>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?> <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pass" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?> <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
    </div>
</li>
```

How can I prevent this autofill, I have tested with jquery disable autocomplete plugin and it does not work

Thanks in advance

Comment: add `autocomplete="off"` attribute on the inputs.

Comment: You may need to use `autocomplete="new-password"` for the password field since a log of browsers ignore off on password fields. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields

Comment: just for information both fields email and password get filled once the page is reloaded

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" 
  autocomplete="off" action="http://www.example.com/form.cgi">
```

This will work in Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox, the downside is that it is not XHTML standard.

Comment: Thanks for this I have tested it but It does not work